# Rails 4: How to to save models in new form with has_many through association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, model-associations

I am new to rails, and I am trying to create a new event that allows a user to select a place and an organization from places and organizations that already exist in the database. I am using a has_many through association. Now I cannot get the event to save, even when I try to save the event without the place_id or organization_id fields.

Models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :place
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :places, through: :events
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :organizations, through: :events
end
```

Event Controller:

```
 def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      render 'show'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :contact, :tag_list, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :long_description, :event_date, :start_time, :end_time, :organization_id, :place_id)
  end
```

New Event View:

```
  <%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :event_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :event_date %>
  <%= f.label :start_time %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_time %>
  <%= f.label :end_time %>
  <%= f.text_field :end_time %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.label :contact %>
  <%= f.text_field :contact %>
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <%= f.label :long_description %>
  <%= f.text_field :long_description %>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  <%= f.submit "Save event", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing here to get the event to save, preferably with organization and place fields that have values of organization_id and place_id?

Comment: Take a look at [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at **[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)** and **[fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)**.And then change your models to like this

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :places, through: :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :organizations, through: :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end
```

So that your event_params would be like this

```
def event_params

params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :contact, :tag_list, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :long_description, :event_date, :start_time, :end_time, places_attributes: [:some_attribute_of_place,..], organizations_attributes: [:some_attribute_of_organization,..)

end
```

And your form could be written as,

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :event_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :event_date %>
  <%= f.label :start_time %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_time %>
  <%= f.label :end_time %>
  <%= f.text_field :end_time %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.label :contact %>
  <%= f.text_field :contact %>
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <%= f.label :long_description %>
  <%= f.text_field :long_description %>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>

  <%= f.fields_for :places do |p| %>

  ---- your code-----

  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :organizations do |o| %>

  ------ your code-----

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save event", class: "button" %>

<% end %>
```